# How to add breadcrumb to Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, breadcrumbs

I use Orchard CMS. I want to add breadcrumb in my blog post page. How can I add breadcrumb.I add menu widget but it shows all the menus.

Comment: What do u mean by "it shows all the menus" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a menu widget, there is a checkbox 'Display as breadcrumb'. 
Just check it and the menu will be displayed as a breadcrumb.

Comment: If I don't want to  show the breadcrumb in the home page what do I do?

Comment: You create a layer NotHomepage and move the widget there.

Comment: @urbanit thank u.In my home page my blog posts are located.I want when a blog post is opened my breadcrumb shows the currect direction(shows the category,...).not to show (home) only!!!